# Android Studio external library

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting to do some projects with this IDE and still I find several anoying situations that where very easy to solve with eclipse but that I don't know how to face here.

I'm implementing mail sending functionality to my app. This must be transparent for the user, so I'm using javax.mail.

For this, I have downloaded the "activation.jar", "additionnal.jar" and "mail.jar" files and I have save them in the libs folder.

Now I'm creating the custom sender class, which extendes **javax.mail.Authenticator**. But it does not find the import for the **javax.mail**, mail is appearing in red. I'm triying to import it from the libs but it does not find them.

I have also included this in gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

I have readed in several questions like this, that the way is to right click on the library and click on **Add as library**, but this option is not appearing for me.

So, whats the way of making Android Studio recognize these libraries?

[image]

Comment: Which build.gradle file did you modify? There are two build.gradle and you should modify the first one which is in the app folder

Comment: @WoookLiu I have modified the one inside app folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to use an artifactory like Sonatype Nexus is for instance. In here you would deploy and retrive your artifacts and artifacts from other remote artifactories. But for now may just use MavenCentral.

In your top level `build.gradle` you would need to configure a repository where your artifacts reside.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() //a public artifactory
    maven {
        url "https://your.privaterepo.com"
    }
}
```

In your project level `build.gradle` you would add a dependency for `javax.mail` like

```
dependencies {
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01' // G:A:V
}
```

For looking up GAV-coordinates of artifacts (**G**roup**A**rtifact**V**ersion) you could use just google, which often points you to http://mvnrepository.com/ where you can easily pick up dependencies in gradle notation.

You then will never need to download artifacts manually, gradle will handle this for you. All you would have to do is, to declare the repository and the dependencies.

For deploying artefacts from gradle, I use a goal `uploadArchives` in my module level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
//noinspection GroovyMissingReturnStatement
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'http://our.private.nexus/nexus/content/repositories/releases') {
                authentication(userName: NEXUS_USERNAME, password: NEXUS_PASSWORD);
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: 'http://our.private.nexus/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots') {
                authentication(userName: NEXUS_USERNAME, password: NEXUS_PASSWORD);
            }
            pom.groupId = "the.groupid.for.this.artifact"
            pom.artifactId = "artifactid"
            pom.version = "1.2.3"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, but we do not have lib in maven and have to add by using jar. we have to add it from project-libs.

Comment: If you generate jars yourself, you would add it to your artifactory to let gradle pick it up. If you build a jar (or aar) inside your project to be used in a different module, you would `compile project (':module_of_the_lib')`

Comment: Well, sounds good and difficult at the same time :). I'll have a try

Answer (score 1):

if you have added libraries into `lib` folder in `src`. It will not going to work.

Click on `android` in project showcase and select `Project`, make new folder as `libs` and then add all third party libraries into it after that when you will right click on it, you will get option to add it as a library.

You also dont need to write in gradle file after adding it. Android Studio automatically add line itself.

Comment: I have the project view selected, there it appears the app folder which contains folders like "build", "libs", "src" and "gradle". So what you mean is that "libs" folder is not the correct one? I'll update my post with a capture

Comment: Updated! If the image is not clear tell and I'll upload it with better quality

Comment: now make a libs folder by right clicking on project name and add folder.after that put jar files into it.

Comment: Sorry, I have uploaded a new pic, in the last one the app folder was not expanded, now it is and the libs folder is shown. There is where I have saved the jar files

Comment: make new folder as i told you in project and add jar files into it.

Comment: you can use maven also to add it directly

Comment: You mean outside app folder?

Comment: How would maven add them directly? I'm still a bit lost with android studio

Comment: I have deleted the current libs folder, created new one, but still doesn't let me to add as library

Answer (score 0):

I usually do a trick with import *.jar libs. After put *.jar files in libs folder. I delete some characters in `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.j'])` and rewrite it to `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`. It's a way to sync my build.gradle :)

Comment: yes, I did it. Everything is ok. @@! Ah, don't forget to click "Sync Now" in the top right.

Comment: @vandaics Ha! I also do something like you just because i don't know how to make studio sync. But now i know how to do that, just like what SatelliteSD said.

Comment: The icon sais "Sync project with gradle files" I believe firmly that this is exactly what you need